# Is the ASP.NET Core NuGET package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.2.7 part of ASP.NET Core 5.0?

Tags: asp.net-core

I am getting a little confused by all the naming and versioning of .NET. I think I understand the whole .NET Framework / Standard / Core thing, but I am now moving into ASP.NET Core territory (I want to give my console application a web interface with Kestrel).

When using the NuGET package manager, I can see the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting` package, needed to run the webserver. But the highest available version is 2.2.7.

Question now, is that 2.2.7 part of ASP.NET Core 5.0, or do I have some configuration incorrect that I do not get the latest version for my application?

And if it is indeed part of ASP.NET Core 5.0, where can I find that reference? [This table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) helped me a lot with understanding the core libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you wanna this document which tells about your package :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting?view=aspnetcore-5.0

And I think you can focus on those classes or interfaces you'll use and take a look if those are supporting .net 5 by click and refer to the details page. You'll see `Applies to` at the bottom of each page such as [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.hosting.ihostingenvironment?view=aspnetcore-5.0#applies-to).

If I misunderstood in some place which made my post isn't suitable to display here, pls point it out and I'll delete it.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I do understand the docs and all, I am just confused by the version numbering of the NuGET package needed to compile and run this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and I also don't know why the version number is set like it but not following the .net core version...